# Mobile devices for developers

Tags: mobile, device

I need to develop some programs for mobile devices but haven't decided the platform to build upon. I'm looking for Palm or Pocket PC devices that have Touch screen and Wi-Fi connection and are cheep because I'll need to buy several of them.

I don't really need camera, mp3 players, video players, pdf readers or anything else since the apps are going to be simple data collection to feed via wireless to a server database.

I'm proficient with C and C#. I could learn Java if I had to.

What devices do you recommend? Linux devices maybe?

PS: Changed the title because I don't want a flamewar between platforms. Please, don't answer with Windows Mobile sucks/rules. I'm looking for devices instead.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

**Windows Mobile**
It supports C#, and Visual Studio comes with the mobile SDK.  So if you know C# you probably already have the tools you need.  And in spite of the iPhone/iPodTouch buzz, the Windows Mobile deployment is still 10X greater.

Answer (score 3):

In order of preference

- [Neo Freerunner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neo_FreeRunner)
- Maemo & the N800 (cheap)
- [Beagleboard](http://beagleboard.org/)

Answer (score 3):

**If you are comfortable with Visual Studio then programming for windows mobile is extremely easy**.  The SDK for mobile comes with emulators for all the latest and popular versions of windows mobile- and you can even debug on teh device itself using a USB cable.

On windows mobile you have a choice: Develop a .Net application or develop native (likely MFC based).  Either one gives you a great development environment.

As far as iPhone development goes- you would **need an apple computer to install and use iPhone SDK**- and you can't run an iPhone app on your phone.  You would have to go through the process of getting it registered with iTunes for you to install your own apps on your own phone!

When I first started playing with mobile development I had a few questions:

- Can I develop using my favorite IDE- Visual Studio.  Will it be as easy as developing a desktop app: **yes.**
- Will I be able to access the internet from my application without 'unlocking' or in some other way enabling the phone that was not intended by the service provider? **yes.**
- Will I be able to access device specific functionality such as GPS easily?  Is there good support for doing so within the API? **Yes.**

Answer (score 1):

You should probably target the Windows Mobile platform. The Palm platform is rather archaic and no longer widely used. The development environment is also rather spartan, while Microsoft has full IDEs available for Windows Mobile development. You might also consider the iPhone/iPod touch platform - I have a feeling the number of devices will multiply at an exponential rate and I've heard that developing applications is much easier due to the completeness of the system stack.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably at least evaluate the Apple [iPod Touch](http://www.apple.com/ipodtouch/). It certainly meets your basic "touch screen + WiFi" spec, and your users presumably won't object to all the the other nice features that will come along for the ride.

I don't know what your cutoff for "cheap" is, but $299 for the base model seems pretty reasonable for a high-quality touch screen and WiFi in a pocketable device.

Comment: you can buy refurbished models from Apple which have new battery and earbuds, cheaper than most eBay offerings

Answer (score 0):

Windows Mobile and CE used to suck, really, really badly. These days however it's definitely passable and worth checking out, especially if you code C#.
Just remember that it is the baby brother of the full framework and has nowhere near enough toys and throws a lot of NotImplementedExceptions. :)

Answer (score 0):

Blackberry publishes its SDK on its web site.  Its apps run J2ME, so with some Java experience it shouldn't be too difficult to get started.  They also give you an emulator.  Disclaimer: I have no experience in writing Blackberry apps, but I looked into it once.

I would not recommend a PalmOS based handset.  I have written code for PalmOS and it's about as painful as writing raw Win32 code in C.  Since Palm has switched its high end handsets to Windows Mobile, PalmOS will just remain stagnant and only run on the slower, less capable hardware.

If I were to write a mobile app, I'd agree that Windows Mobile is worth checking out.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the users who you are targeting at, If you are looking for a wide market then you should be fine with J2ME/Blackberry . However most of them lack the touchscreen and wifi features ( The HTC range of phones [WIFI/TouchScreen/Windows Mobile] have a JVM built with it),so it would work on most of the Windows devices also.

If you are making a more niche product, moving with the current buzz 'iphone' will be good . Windows Mobile is also worth checking out

Answer (score 0):

The best option here would be the Neo Freerunner, with that device you can build a dedicated unit were every aspect is made especially for you're needs. The Freerunner is WiFi enabled, and has a touch interface. If you use the Qt SDK, a lot of the work is already done for you. It comes complete with emulator, as a Live linux cd. You can run in a WM, such as wmplayer. Everything is included.

I'm not gonna lie, it will take tweaking. But the final product would be really nice and intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at Windows Mobile devices, your requirement of touchscreen pretty much sets your pricing at the higher end of the spectrum. You'll get those things you say you don't need just because of that.

Here's [expansys](http://www.expansys.com/smartphone#tabstate=0&subfolder=1771)'s selection of touchscreens.

[Mobdeal](http://www.mobdeal.com/phones.asp?t=1&adv=o&man=&network=&gift=&tariff=) is a handy one too as that effectively filters all phones by features.

I've developed against the [HTC TYTN 2, HTC Touch Diamond](http://www.htc.com/europe/product_all.aspx) and randomly a [PSION Teklogix Ikon](http://www.psionteklogix.com/products/handheld/ikon.htm)

There's generally very little difference between these models, some manufacturers have SDKs that can help sometimes.

I think your cheapest option will probably be something like getting HTC TYTN 2s on ebay. They're pretty old now (hence cheap) but have Wifi, camera, touchscreen, qwerty keypad all the things you seem to be after.

Answer (score 0):

you can target iPhone "touch" platform with Apple's iPhone SDK. the development environment requires a Mac, but you can get the entire IDE + tool chain + excellent debugging and profiling tools *for free*.  And the free documentation is top notch.

As a registered iPhone developer, it is free (no cost) to target the simulator, which is sufficient for most learning and development you'll likely need to up front.

To target the actual hardware device (and up to and including release/selling your app on the Apple's AppStore) is only $99/yr. If you got an iPod Touch for your hardware target, most of the SDK applies and you are not tied into a service contract for an iPhone.

iPhone app development environment is in Objective-C, but it is a really productive, object-oriented environment so do not concerned that that may be a language you are unfamiliar with.

If you decide that your mobile app(s) would be better suited as webapps, the iPhone/iPod touch platform again is an industry leader in this space, and you have the additional benefit or being able to target other mobile platforms (and not necessarily be tied to one mobile SDK).